# 'SET_ON' in C programming

Tags: c

When I was reading the C programming language book, I came across this:

```
x = x | SET_ON;
```

What does this do? Is 'SET_ON' a keyword in C? Or does the author just try to explain what '|' does?

Comment: It's a constant or macro defined somewhere in the code. The meaning or what it does depends on how it is defined, which we can't know because it's not in the single, totally out of context line of code you posted.

Comment: Did you skip parts of the book? Because it should explain what `SET_ON` is. It's not a part of the C language. It's obviously some identifier with a particular value that is needed for the bitwise-OR operation being performed here, but only the book can tell you what it's value is and why it's useful.

Comment: No. I read each line carefully looking to see any clues but I could not. But thanks for your help. At first, I though it was an operator but then I could not find it anywhere on the Internet. So I decided to ask this as a question whether this was part of C itself.

Comment: 'could not find it anywhere on the Internet' yes, you are searching in the wrong place.  grep for it, (ie. search for the text locally, look in .h files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipe symbol `|` takes two variables and does a bitwise-or on them.

The truth table for bitwise-or is:

```
A | B | Result
0 | 0 | 0
0 | 1 | 1
1 | 0 | 1
1 | 1 | 1
```

So, if `x` is `A` in the truth table and you want to "turn on" a bit, you'd have `B` equal one. Otherwise, `x` is unaffected.

Of course that only tells us the idea, not what `SET_ON` is doing specifically. For instance, if `SET_ON=0xFF`, then it turns on *all* the bits (in the least-significant byte).

`SET_ON` is not part of the C language: it is defined by whatever library or code you're looking at. If you can't find the definition, you'll have to figure it out from context/description.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "pipe operator" in C. Only the shell uses that symbol for pipes. Therefore the "bitwise or operator" should not be called a "pipe operator".

Comment: @Gerhardh: I've reworded to "pipe symbol".

Answer (score 0):

SET_ON is likely a defined macro whose value is 1. Somewhere in one of the headers you use, you will find:

```
#define SET_ON    1
```

With this define, whenever the compiler sees "SET_ON" in the code, it will replace this symbol with the value 1.

In this context, performing `(X | SET_ON)` evaluates to `1` (or more depending on the initial value of X). Any non-zero value evaluates to `true` when tested logically in C, so regardless of the value of X, (X | SET_ON) will be true.

It is a quick method for setting a bool flag to true, and is usually more useful when performing this operation on an array of booleans stored within an int. In your example, it looks like X is used to store a logical value of either false (0) or true (non-zero).

So `X = X | SET_ON;` is equivalent to `X = X | 1;` which is equivalent to setting X to a non-zero value (logically true).

Answer (score -1):

It's likely a macro or a variable defined somewhere in that code. It's not a part of the language itself.